# eslint await Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, async-await, lint, eslint, ecmascript-2017

When I place this code for a promise that the result is not needed to proceed:

```
await resultNotNeeded(bla, foo);
```

I'm getting this eslint error:

> [eslint] Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression. (no-unused-expressions)

If the code is like this:

```
const dummy = await resultNotNeeded(bla, foo);
```

Then the eslint error is:

> [eslint] 'dummy' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)

Anyone knows how this should be fixed (I know I could do `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions`but I'm looking if there is a better syntax for this statement.

Comment: What if the async code fails?

Comment: Well if you don't need the result, then it *is* an unused expression. Just disable the rule.

Comment: Admittedly, it's a bug in the rule. If they want to allow function calls for side effects, they should also allow `await` expressions. Please report it at eslints issue tracker.

Comment: @thefourtheye, for that case, which I think is not the problem here, await is surrounded in a `try {} catch {}` block which I haven't written here to simplify and focus the question to the problem. @bergi, thanks, it was a problem that eslint was not updated

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm a little confused and tried to search around the web but there is a lot of buzz. Does it mean that I can't use it in node with babel? What are the implications? Will be a polyfill always needed?

Comment: *"Does it mean that I can't use it in node with babel?"* No, Babel allows you to use (future) features that are not natively supported yet. That's exactly what Babel enables you to do. *"What are the implications?"* Just that is not officially part of the language yet. *"Will be a polyfill always needed?"* Once the feature is officially part of the language, engines will natively support it (sonner or later). ES7 (ES2016) was released around June this year. `async/await` is currently a proposal scheduled for release next year: https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md

Answer (score 5):

This problem is fixed in `eslint@3.6.0`.

The problem is that eslint was not updated in my system, I had `eslint@2.13.1`. Also npm was not up to date, so `npm i eslint@latest -g` was not updating eslint.

I had to install `npm@3.10.7` (firstly I updated to `npm@3.10.8` but it was not working, so I had to download source code from npm github and `sudo make install`) and then I could update `eslint@3.7.0`.

Hope it helps!